# microtype, csquotes active quotes and itemize interaction

Tags: itemize, microtype, csquotes

I've met today a bad interaction between `microtype`, `csquotes` autoquotes, and the `itemize` environment, essentially leading to a "`forgotten \endgroup`" error.

A MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item “foo”
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Which leads to error:

```
./document.tex:11: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }
                 
l.11 \item “
              foo”
./document.tex:12: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.12 \end{itemize}
```

I can only reproduce when both packages are loaded and the active quote immediately follows `\item` (passing an empty optional argument to it does not change things).

Am I missing something, or is this really a bad interaction between the packages? (I'm pretty sure this used to work, but my memory is known to have failed in similar instances...). If it is indeed, I suppose a report is due. I'd gladly do it, but I'm not sure whom to with this. Pointers in that regard are welcome. As is some temporary workaround.

Comment: your memory doesn't fool you, this is a new bug in `microtype`. A temporary workaround would be to add `\microtypesetup{nopatch=item} (either for the whole document or just around the itemize environment). See chapter 9 of the doc.

Comment: @Robert It seems to be it. Thank you very much! If you'd like to elaborate it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept. I'll prepare a bug report for `microtype` later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** This has been fixed in `microtype` version 3.0a.

---

Beginning with version 3.0, `microtype` applies some patches to improve protrusion at "inner margins", e.g. at the beginning of `\item`s (see chapter 9 of the `microtype` doc). This requires some gymnastics, and here the active character from `csquotes` interferes. A quick fix would be to prevent the patching with `\microtypesetup{nopatch=item}`, either for the whole document or only the problematic case. A better fix (which will be included in the next version) would be to patch the pertinent `microtype` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{“}{”}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\microtypesetup{nopatch=item} 
  \item “foo” some more text\\ “another quote”
\end{itemize}

\makeatletter 
\patchcmd\MT@get@prot{\noindent}{\noindent\@disablequotes}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{itemize}
  \item “foo” some more text\\ “another quote”
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

(In a real document, you'd move the `\MT@get@prot` patch to the preamble, of course.)

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much! I have opened an issue: https://github.com/schlcht/microtype/issues/1, but considering the phrasing of your answer, I suppose "R" stands for Robert, in which case, feel free to just close there. :)

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks, and yes, your guess is right.

Comment: One more reason to thank you, then. I'm looking forward to the next version (with no hush).